# Best opensource software for inforgraphics

Tags: open-source, web-development, web, node.js

I wanted to know which is best opensource software for info-graphics (Dashboards) which can be embedded to web app. previously we were using Power BI( which gives us lots of costs) and Metabase (not flexible as has limited customization)

Thanks inadvance for your answers